# showing highest sum as result

Tags: sum, max

Maybe there's someone who can help me.

I've got 5 tables from which I would have the sum per table and show the highest sum.

I've tried this, but I got an error.

```
$best_browser_query = mysql_query("select max(sum(google_browser_ie), sum(google_browser_sa), sum(google_browser_ch), sum(google_browser_ff), sum(google_browser_an)) as sum_amount from site_google_browsers limit 1");
while ($best_browser = mysql_fetch_array($best_browser_query)) {
echo '<tr>' .
'  <td class="adm_box_text2">' . TEXT_BEST_BROWSER . '</td>' .
'  <td class="adm_box_text2">' . $best_browser['sum_amount'] . '</td>' .
'</tr>';
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use max on columns, you may try following query:

```
select max (sum_amount) from
(select sum(google_browser_ie) as sum_amount union
        sum(google_browser_sa)union
        sum(google_browser_ch) union
        sum(google_browser_ff) union
        sum(google_browser_an)from site_google_browsers limit 1") a;
```